# Best in-depth analytics or stats tools? (preferrably server-side)

Tags: statistics, analytics, visitors

I know there's been questions about this before, but mine is a little more specific. I work for a high traffic website and we want to start tracking our visitors better. Unfortunately, Google Analytics is not an option at the moment, so what I'm looking for is some alternatives, preferrably server-side (but not necessarily).

We're currently running Urchin, but what I'm missing most there is the way you can set conversions in Analytics and then track (for example) which keywords convert better or which landing pages convert better. Also, A/B testing is something I really miss.

Which analytics tools can be compared to analytics in terms of advanced segmentation, navigation summaries, A/B testing, etc?

Comment: You know that Google Analytics is basically Urchin, right? Also, what platform are you running the site on as without knowing what server you have, we can't suggest server-side tools.

Comment: I know, but Analytics is not server-side. Also, Urchin is missing some of the key features like advanced segmentation, A/B testing as well as an easy on the eye overview like Analytics has. Anyway, it's all linux/apache/php :)

Comment: I was just checking. I still know some people that think otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the budget for the truly high-end tracking platforms big corp uses, the best tools for analytics, conversion tracking and A/B testing are specialized specific services.

There's [MixPanel](http://mixpanel.com/), [KissMetrics](http://kissmetrics.com), [Performable](http://www.performable.com) and [w3roi](http://www.w3roi.com)* for the conversion/event/revenue tracking side.

Check out [Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/), [Optimizely](http://www.optimizely.com/), [Unbounce](http://www.unbounce.com) and of course [Google Website Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) for split testing.

`*` Disclaimer: w3roi's a tool I built for my own needs, but it's relevant so I mention it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SmartStats](http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx) before. And [Mint](http://haveamint.com/) is goods.

Both are good, but I don't know about using them with A/B testing.

Comment: I have Mint as well, but it's not suitable for what I'm looking for. I'll check out SmartStats, thanks.